# record structures,arrays and finding max using a function

Tags: vb.net, max, user-defined-functions, dynamic-arrays, return-type

I have a visual basic problem. I have a record structure which has 4 variables and one of them is an array.I have trouble finding the max. The function returns the same value for all champions. The days on which the champions get their best scores varies and so should the value returned by the function but it doesn't

```
Private Structure DebateChamps
  ' user will input the name of each debate champion
  ' the user will also input the scores of each champion
  ' the bestday---day on which a champion attained highest score, 
  ' and average for each champion are for me to work out
    Public Name As String
    Public Score() As Double
    Public Average As Double
    Public BestDay As Integer
```

I have worked out the first three but now I am having trouble with finding the best day. I want to do this using a function. I know that finding the best day essentially means finding the max. This is what I have for finding the best day. The problem with it is that when I output it onto the grid, I get the same values every time. For example lets say Champion 1 has scores

> 9(day 1),8(day 2),6(day 3)

and Champion 2 has scores

> 7(day 1),5(day 2),9(day 3)

I will get day 3 as the best day for both. Please help.

I pass array into the function
I want it to return an array because,there are numerous days and each day may vary for each champion

```
Private Function ComputeBestDay(ByVal ChampAry() As DebateChamps) As Integer()

    Dim Max(nChamps, nDays) As Double
    Dim MaxIndex(nChamps) As Integer

    Dim r, c As Integer

    'I initialise the max values to zero
    'and the index as well
    For r = 1 To nChamps
        For c = 1 To nDays
            Max(r, c) = 0
            MaxIndex(r) = 0
        Next c
    Next r

    'I try to find the max
    'I store the day in MaxIndex
    For r = 1 To nChamps
        For c = 1 To nDays
            If Max(r, c) < ChampAry(r).Score(c) Then
                Max(r, c) = ChampAry(r).Score(c)
                MaxIndex(r) = c
            End If
        Next c
    Next r

    Return MaxIndex

End Function
```

I call the function below

```
Private Sub btnBestDay_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnBestDay.Click

    Dim i As Integer
    Dim ans(nChamps) As Integer

    'I call the function
    For i = 1 To nChamps
        ans = ComputeBestDay(AllChampsAry)
        AllChampsAry(i).BestDay = ans(i)
        placetext(i, nDays + 2, CStr(AllChampsAry(i).BestDay))
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: I have trouble finding the max. The function returns the same value for all champions. The days on which the champions get their best scores varies and so should the value returned by the function but it doesn't

Comment: I will repost the problem later today. Sorry, new to this and really tired.

Comment: you need to define for us what you mean by max.  Max champ for a day?  Max of all champs for all Days?  ...and what does that have to do with `BestDay`??

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it using LINQ:

```
Private Function ComputeBestDay(ByVal ChampAry() As DebateChamps) As Integer()

    Return ChampAry _
        .Select(Function (r) _
            Enumerable _
                .Range(0, r.Score.Length) _
                .First(Function (c) r.Score(c) = r.Score.Max())) _
        .ToArray()

End Function
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. I was instructed to use a function that calculates the position of the max. I was confused because of the record structure. In my record structure I have the following

```
    Private Structure DebateChamps


    Public Name As String
    Public Score() As Double
    Public Average As Double
    Public BestDay As Integer

End Structure
```

Lets say a school principal wants to pick the best debate team----hence the structure name DebateChamps. To do this he will pick the names that have an average of greater than five. The records for each champion go into the array

```
   Private AllChampsAry() As DebateChamps
```

Handling the input and average was straight forward. The principal also wants to find on which day the players performed best. So I had to display the maxindex for each player.

```
    Dim max As Double
    Dim index(nChamps) As Integer
    Dim r, c As Integer

    For r = 1 To nChamps
        max = 0
        For c = 1 To nDays
            If max < ChampAry(r).Score(c) Then
                max = ChampAry(r).Score(c)
                index(r) = c
            End If
        Next c
    Next
```

First loop through each champ(candidate for debate championship) then through the days for each champ(assume each champ participated for the same number of days)...I stored the indices for each champ in an array and the returned it.
I was confused due to the record structures.I had never used them before